# Inherited Text-Decoration style

Tags: css, text-decorations, line-through

How would I negate or remove a parents text-decoration style? For example in the following, both the text and the anchor have a text-decoration of line-through, is there a way to not have that applied to the anchor tag?

```html
<span style="text-decoration:line-through;">
    Dead Text 
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:underline;color:Red;">Not Dead Text</a>
</span>
```

NOTE: wrapping the inner text in a span isn't an easy option with what I have so I'm looking for a solution based on the css styles if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following line in the accepted answer is incorrect:

> Any text decoration setting on a
>   descendant box can never “undo” the
>   text decorations of an ancestor box.

Never say never, right?

I have not found a solution for IE yet (unless you happen to be working with a scenario where the strikethrough is set on a `<TD>`) however it *is* possible for other browsers, although you will have to battle the side-effects of the solution.

See for yourself at http://result.dabblet.com/gist/3713284/

In short: just add `display:table;` to the child's style. For some reason in FF you can use any of `table`, `block`, `list-item` or `table-caption` but these don't work in Safari/Chrome.

It uses the code below:

```html
<span style="text-decoration:line-through;">
   Dead Text
   <a href="#" style="text-decoration:underline;color:Red;">Undesired strikethrough</a>
</span>

<div style="text-decoration:line-through;">
  Dead Text
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration:underline;color:Red; display: table;">display: table in a div</a>
</div>

<span style="text-decoration:line-through;">
  Dead Text
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration:underline;color:Red; display:  table;">display: table in a span</a>
</span>

<span style="text-decoration:line-through; display: block;">
  Dead Text
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration:underline;color:Red; display: table;">display: table in a span with "display:block;"</a>
</span>

<span style="text-decoration:line-through; display: table-cell;">
  Dead Text
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration:underline;color:Red; display: table;">display: table in a span with "display:table-cell;"</a>
</span>

<span style="text-decoration:line-through;">
  Dead Text
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration:underline;color:Red; display: list-item;">display: list-item</a>
</span>

<span style="text-decoration:line-through;">
  Dead Text
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration:underline;color:Red; display: table-caption;">display: table-caption;</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Unfortunately these workarounds appear to have stopped working. In Chromium 80, no text decoration gets negated by these solutions. In Firefox 72, only `display: table-caption` remains standing.

Comment: @bleistift2 Currently the `display: inline-block` in a span or a div or `display: inline-table` in a span or a div seems to work in most browsers. I've set up a more detailed test at http://result.dabblet.com/gist/3713284/. I'll update my answer later this day/week when I have time.

Answer (score 7):

I just found, that if you set position: absolute for block, it will work  both in chrome and FF:

```html
<span style="text-decoration:line-through;">
Dead Text 
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:underline;color:Red;">This not works</a>
</span>
<br/>
<span style="text-decoration:line-through;">
Dead Text 
<a href="#" style="position: absolute;margin-left: 5px;text-decoration:underline;color:Red;">This works</a>
</span>
```

Ugly, but can help in some cases;

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe it's possible. From [SitePoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-decoration):

> Also, text decorations on inline boxes
>   are rendered along the entire box,
>   even if it contains descendant boxes.
>   This, too, may appear similar to
>   inheritance. Any text decoration
>   setting on a descendant box can never
>   “undo” the text decorations of an
>   ancestor box.

Comment: Ugh. That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for the answer and the link, that explained it well!

Comment: Actually, under a specific set of circumstances it *is* possible! I Added a more complete description in my answer below :-)

Answer (score 2):

This works as well: `display: inline-block`

```html
<span style="text-decoration:line-through;">
Dead Text 
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:underline;color:Red;">This not works</a>
</span>
<br/>
<span style="text-decoration:line-through;">
Dead Text 
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:underline;color:blue;display:inline-block">This works</a>
</span>
```