# Can't I override text-decoration to none?

Tags: css, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get this CSS text-decoration override to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823341/how-do-i-get-this-css-text-decoration-override-to-work)

Chrome and Firefox are conspiring to thwart my attempt to have a td with the line-through text-decoration, sometimes disabled by a span, like so:

```
<style type="text/css">
tr.st td {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

tr.st td span.unstrike{
  text-decoration: none;
  background:yellow;
}

tr.st td span#unstrike-id{
  text-decoration: none;
  background:yellow;
}

tr.st td span.unstrike-important{
  text-decoration: none ! important;
  background:yellow;
}

</style>


<table  border>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>normal</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="st">
        <td>struck out</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="st">
        <td>struck out <span class="unstrike">unstrike class: shouldn't I be normal?</span></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="st">
        <td>struck out <span id="unstrike-id">unstrike-id identifier.  Shouldn't I be normal?</span></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="st">
        <td>struck out <span class="unstrike-important">unstrike-important: shouldn't I  be even more normal?</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I'm squinting at the spec and I don't get it.

Special case for text-deocration?  What gives?

demo [here](http://danny.sadinoff.com/bugdemo/cascade/line-through-cascade.html)

Comment: Wow, that's interesting, it would seem the `text-decoration` is being applied to the whole TD's contents and ignoring whatever is underneath it. Never seen that.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1261974/698179 - It may well be better to put a `span` in all of your `td`s, and apply styling individually as a child element.

Comment: Yes, I see it now, Although I think this is the best precedent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823341/how-do-i-get-this-css-text-decoration-override-to-work/1823388#1823388

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific sequence to which line-decoration to use the property, you can use `:nth-child()`

Or try to add line-decoration to span, not to td. Look my example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qVYCg/)

Answer (score 0):

The strike-through is applied to the table cell, rather than it's contents. A similar case would be applying a border to the `<td>`. Removing the border on the span will not stop the border on the td shining through.

You could add an opaque background to the span.

---

Adding:

```
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
top: 0px;
```

[seems to fix it.](http://jsfiddle.net/qVYCg/1/)

Comment: Mostly I was looking for some explanation from the spec why this would be so.  There are lots of fixes. Yours is definitely interesting.  

I would, however, hesitate to use it without a deeper understanding of why it works, and why inline-block works but an ordinary block (say a div) doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this is a dupe of several questions, in particular:

[How do I get this CSS text-decoration override to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823341/how-do-i-get-this-css-text-decoration-override-to-work/1823388#1823388)

In short, the (to me very fuzzy) language at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-decoration  says "no override".

Moderators/editors, please close me as a dupe.