# line-through not working as should

Tags: css

class .slogan has "text-decoration: line-through;", but "span" has "text-decoration: none;" Why is it not canceling it?

```css
header {
  background: #34abf8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.slogan {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  font-size: 4.5em;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
.slogan span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.45em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="slogan">
  This text is underlined. <span>But this shouldn't be underlined</span>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: Because you can't override the parent's property like that with text-decoration

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inherited Text-Decoration style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261955/inherited-text-decoration-style)

Answer (score 2):

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#lining-striking-props) states it clearly:

> The 'text-decoration' property on descendant elements cannot have any
>   effect on the decoration of the ancestor.

However, text decorations are propagated to the contents of descendants unless they are displayed as atomic inline-level elements, floated, positioned `absolute`ly.

> **[16.3.1 Underlining, overlining, striking, and blinking: the 'text-decoration' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#lining-striking-props)**
>
> [...] Note that text decorations are not propagated to floating and
>   absolutely positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic
>   inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables.

Therefore, you could change the `display` of the span to `inline-block` in order to prevent the `<span>` element from being affected by decoration of the parent:

```css
header {
  background: #34abf8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.slogan {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  font-size: 4.5em;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
.slogan span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.45em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="slogan">
  This text is underlined. <span>But this shouldn't be underlined</span>
  </div>

</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a property of the text nodes, it's the entire `.slogan` element that has `line-through`.

For example, you can see here that `two` is underlined twice because both `.slogan` and `span` are underlined.

```css
.slogan {
   text-decoration: underline;
   font-size: 20px;
}

.slogan span {
   font-size: 10px;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="slogan">
   one ... <span> two </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`span` has an `inline` `display` , reset the `display` to anything else than `inline` should allow you to override parent `text-decoration` on its content.

added a `<b>` to let you see defaut behavior of inline element.

```css
header {
  background: #34abf8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.slogan {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  font-size: 4.5em;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
.slogan span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.45em;
  text-decoration: none;
  display:inline-block
}
b {padding:0.25em;}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="slogan">
  This text is underlined. <span>But this shouldn't be underlined</span> <b>&nbsp;</b>
  </div>

</header>
```