# Unable to remove text-decoration from label

Tags: html, css

I have the following example HTML:

```
<div class="a">
    <div>
        <ul class="b">
            <li class="c">
                <input id="123" type="checkbox" checked></input>
                <label for="123">test</label>
            </li>
            <li class="c">
                <input id="456" type="checkbox"></input>
                <label for="456">test</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.a {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.a .b .c input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

This can be found at this JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4q8a7yox/1/

I would like to remove the line-through from all labels for unchecked items. The weird thing is that Chrome console shows the 'computed' text-decoration as 'none', yet it still shows it. All browsers (IE10 and FF) fail in a similar way. Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261955/inherited-text-decoration-style) that's not possible. You cannot remove text-decoration properties for children nodes.

So the best thing to do is not adding the `text-decoration: line-through;` to your .a elements and then trying to remove it for unchecked inputs, but instead adding the line-through only for checked inputs.

EDIT: try this https://jsfiddle.net/b2bL8ksn/

Comment: so it's a bug in HTML/CSS spec? it doesn't make any sense, you can remove any other CSS style

Comment: Cause that's not technically inheritance. Read this, it will explain far better than I can do: http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/text-decoration-css-property/

Comment: thank you, this explains it. this is probably the least intuitive design i have seen in quite awhile. a shame it is done this way.

Comment: reading again the link i provided, it seems like you can avoid transmitting the line-through if you "take away" the children from the parent box. So i've tried setting an absolute position, and it seems to work (on safari mac at least). See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector from `.a` to `label`.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4q8a7yox/2/)**

```
label {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

EDIT:

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4q8a7yox/4)**

use more specificity. Drill down into the html label. for this example it would be:

```
.a > div > .b > .c > label { 
   text-decoration: line-through; 
}
```

Comment: this would be for all labels which is not desired. this is part of a much bigger CSS for a web application, i've made it simple for this example

Comment: @automaton Then use more specificity. drill down into the html label. for this example it would be `.a > div > .b > .c > label {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Can you just reverse the css?

```
.a .b .c input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Comment: at the moment no because the condition of line-through is actually applied at the parent under a different condition. i've made the example easier

Answer (score 0):

Please use this css. i have just little changed on your CSS.

```
   .a .b .c input[type=checkbox] + label {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    }

   .a .b .c input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label {
    text-decoration: inherit !important;
   }
```

Comment: But I hate `!important` :)

Comment: me too hate !important. but if other css is there with same classes may be there is a chance for overflow. :)

Comment: specifically targeting the child will work, you are right. however i am curious why it must be done that way, when other CSS styles can be applied on the parent and removed on the children? doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
.a .c input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
text-decoration: line-through; }
```